# Paypal recurring credit card subscription with google cloud functions and firestore

Tags: paypal, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to implement direct credit card subscription using the paypal-rest-sdk for node and google cloud functions (no need for paypal account) to setup monthly subscriptions. I want each monthly payment processing to call a webhook which sets a paidTill: now+1 month.

I have found this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/ and this https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/paypal/functions/index.js

My questions are:

1) how do I use the firebase server time timestamp but add +1 month to it as I do a firebase firestore database .set() operation?

2) Is it just a case of swapping out the single payment call with the code from the billing agreement code? What is the best way to test this and how do I ensure that paypal updates my database every month? Do they fire off a web hook call every time a recurring payment is made?